# How to timeout hanging requests in ASP.NET Web API 2.2

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I have ASP.NET Web API 2.2 application which is running on IIS 10. When i was monitor request on IIS then realized some requests hanging forever. I tried following ways to timeout these requests after 120 seconds but didn't work.

Is there any way to kill (timeout) these hanging requests which makes slow down the app?

in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="120" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```

in Controller

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 60;
```

and in IIS App Pool

> [image: Blockquote]

Hanging Requests on IIS
[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your settings, clearing the cache and trying again.

Comment: i did not just clear cache i reset the server and nothing change :) Some resources says Web Api 2 does not support timeout but i am not sure. @samwu

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, one of our engineers will help find the root cause.